# Animated background pattern that follows cursor

Tags: html, css

http://mahno.com.ua/en
I really wanted the effect of the pattern following your mouse in the background, as seen on the home page of the website above.

I found this demo to use, (Demo 1)
http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/ 
But I found it difficult to edit the code. I managed to make the background white and remove the text etc.

I cant find the container that holds the actual animation as I want it to continue down the whole page. And I cant add my own text unless it is inside the heading tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Try to use `particle.js` . Here is a codepen http://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso

Comment: @SimonM. I was actually looking for this plug in the other day but couldn't remember the name, so in a way, you helped 2 people!

Comment: thank you so much. that worked like a charm :D

Comment: I've edited the background colour speed, removed the particle count etc. but do you know how to set a max amount of particles? @SimonM.

Comment: @LeandraDreyer If you want to set more particle, you just have to change the `value` in `particles` { `number`. Check this [page](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) you have all the setting available